# Registering a SQL function with JPA/Hibernate without Dialect Class

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-function, dialect

I'm having a rought time trying to calculate duration between two dates in Hql, so I've read in a post that I have to register the hql funtion using a custom dialect,
but the probleme is I'm working on an open source project and I don't want to be attached to a specific DBMS implementation,

so now I'm tryning to register an SQL function into hibernate configuration `Configuration.addSqlFunction(...)`
but I don't how to get hold of my Configuration object when the app starts.

here is how i initilalize hibernate

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Subclass MetadataBuilderContributor.

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor
        implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
         
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "group_concat",
            new StandardSQLFunction(
                "group_concat",
                StandardBasicTypes.STRING
            )
        );
    }
}
```

This example is from https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/